# 21.04 Install does not find secondary display

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, display, 21.04

Booting 21.04 from usb stick.

Desktop works across both primary and secondary monitors.

Install Ubuntu and reboot

Secondary screen shows only mouse cursor, no desktop.

Using ubuntu public drivers on two identical nvidia video cards and two indentical screens.

(I'm putting this here so I can answer myself - maybe it will help others)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Disable Wayland

Commentary:

The Wayland config built by the install is bad.

Installing nvidia drivers and config program shows secondary card as 'disabled' (and can't enable)

Examining video config with Xrandr between booted and installed shows major differences